# MATLAB getframe not capturing desired image

Tags: matlab

the code below is from "Numerical Computing with Matlab".

I'm trying to capture an image of all the points produced (that matlab can't save due to the 'erasemode','none' condition). I've tried putting F=getframe at the end of the while loop, and after the while loop (when the stop button is pressed), but all these result in only one point being captured.

```
nmax = 100;
n = 2:nmax;
kappalo = n.^(1/2);
kappahi = 500*n.^3;

shg
clf reset
h = loglog(n,[kappalo; kappahi],'-',nmax,NaN,'.');
set(h(1:2),'color',[0 2/3 0]);
set(gca,'xtick',[2:2:10 20:20:nmax])
kappamax = 1.e6;
axis([2 nmax 2 kappamax])
stop = uicontrol('pos',[20 10 40 25], ...
   'style','toggle','string','stop','value',0);

h = h(3);
set(h,'erasemode','none','color','blue')
while get(stop,'value') ~= 1
   n = ceil(rand*nmax);
   A = randn(n,n);
   kappa = condest(A);
   set(h,'xdata',n,'ydata',kappa)
   drawnow            % Tried replacing drawnow with getframe
                      % Tried it here, after drawnow: F = getframe;
end

% Tried here, F = getframe; or F = getframe(gcf);


set(stop,'val',0,'string','close','callback','close(gcf)')

% Tried here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the erasemode property is ignored by getframe. Knowing that getframe rerenders a figure, it's probably a limitation that simply has to be accepted. Not using the property, I get the expected results.

```
nmax = 100;
n = 2:nmax;
kappalo = n.^(1/2);
kappahi = 500*n.^3;

shg
clf reset
h = loglog(n,[kappalo; kappahi],'-',nmax,NaN,'.');
set(h(1:2),'color',[0 2/3 0]);
set(gca,'xtick',[2:2:10 20:20:nmax])
kappamax = 1.e6;
axis([2 nmax 2 kappamax])
stop = uicontrol('pos',[20 10 40 25], ...
   'style','toggle','string','stop','value',0);

h = h(3);
set(h,'color','blue')
n=nan(10000,1);
kappa=nan(10000,1);
ix=1;
while get(stop,'value') ~= 1
   an = ceil(rand*nmax);
   A = randn(an,an);
   akappa = condest(A);
   n(ix)=an;
   kappa(ix)=akappa;
   set(h,'xdata',n,'ydata',kappa)
   drawnow            % Tried replacing drawnow with getframe
                         % Tried it here, after drawnow: F = getframe;
   ix=ix+1;
end
x=getframe;
set(stop,'val',0,'string','close','callback','close(gcf)')
```